# device.newDefaultLibrary() returns nil

Tags: ios, ios8, metal

After I installed XCode 6 GM, application, compiled by it started to return nil at Metal Framework device.newDefaultLibrary() call. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your device to iOS 8 GM and it will stop failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try use - (nullable id )newDefaultLibraryWithBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle error:(__autoreleasing NSError **)error