# Running Metal and Swift on the iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, swift, metal

Was really excited to find [Warren Moore's sample project](https://github.com/warrenm/slug-swift-metal/) using Metal and Swift, but when I try to run it on my device (5s, 8.2, XCode 6.2), I get an error saying that the `Info.plist [...] specifies device capability requirements, which are not met by Davis's iPhone`.

As far as I can tell, the only relevant `Key`s in the `plist` are:

```
Required device capabilities: armv7, metal
Application requires iPhone environment: YES
```

I have to assume that `armv7` means `armv7` *or later*, in which case, the 5s should [qualify](http://iossupportmatrix.com/).  And anyway at [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) they kept saying it would work on A7, which was introduced on the 5s.

**What I've tried:**

1. I removed the requirements (felt like a bad idea), after which I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.  A little digging around shows that `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` is returning `nil`.
2. This lead me to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757157/device-newdefaultlibrary-returns-nil) where the solution was to update iOS, but both Xcode and iOS are up to date.

Comment: The git project you linked to says it's from in November.  I'm pretty sure both Swift and Xcode have been updated twice since then (at least once for sure).  The problem likely isn't that your Xcode/iOS are out of date, but more likely that the project itself isn't up to date with the current version of Swift/Xcode which has been extremely volatile in its youth.

Comment: Sounds reasonable--I'll keep working my way through the Metal documentation, and see if I can find where along the line the code broke.

Comment: 5S is definitely able to run Metal. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html